# Template specialisation failure for a templated structure inside a templated structure

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, partial-specialization

I can't seem to wrap my head around what is going wrong with the following example

```
$ cat repro.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
struct S1_t
{
  template<class U>
  struct inner_t_x {};

  using inner_t = inner_t_x<T>;
};
struct Bogus{};

template<class T>
struct Functor1
{
  void operator()() 
  {
    cout << "Functor1 FAIL: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  }
};
template<>
struct Functor1<typename S1_t<Bogus>::template inner_t_x<Bogus>>
{
  void operator()() 
  {
    cout << "Functor1 PASS: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  }
};

template<class T>
struct Functor2
{
  void operator()() 
  {
    cout << "Functor2 FAIL: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  }
};
template<class T>
struct Functor2<typename S1_t<T>::template inner_t_x<T>>
{
  void operator()() 
  {
    cout << "Functor2 PASS: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  }
};

template<class T>
void eval()
{
  Functor1<T>{}();
  Functor2<T>{}();
}

int main()
{
  eval<S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t>();
  return 0;
}

$ clang++ repro.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall && ./a.out
Functor1 PASS: void Functor1<S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t_x<Bogus> >::operator()()
Functor2 FAIL: void Functor2<S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t_x<Bogus> >::operator()() [T = S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t_x<Bogus>]
```

In the `Functor1`, I explicitly specialise on the type `Bogus`, and indeed that specialisation is being invoked. However, in the `Functor2` the type is allowed to be deduced, but partial specialisation fails  and generic template is instantiated instead. Yet, `__PRETTY_PRINT__` show the same signature for `Functor1` & `Functort2` when instantiated.

Can anyone able to explain this behaviour, and is there a way to fix `Functor2` partial specialisation to fit this scenario? Thanks!

fwiw: Changing `Functor2` partial specialisation to

```
template<class T>
struct Functor2<typename S1_t<Bogus>::template inner_t_x<T>>
{
  void operator()() 
  {
    cout << "Functor2 PASS: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
  }
};
```

gives correct output

```
Functor1 PASS: void Functor1<S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t_x<Bogus> >::operator()()
Functor2 PASS: void Functor2<S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t_x<Bogus> >::operator()() [T = S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t_x<Bogus>]
```

but this is not the option in my use case.

Comment: Why is there no type in `template<> struct Functor1`? Maybe it is just some special syntax that I don't know, but it looks odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specialization of `Functor2` will never be used. The compiler could issue a warning about that, but it doesn't in your case. The reason for it being not deducible is simple: Imagine you later add something like

```
struct Hogus;

template<>
struct S1_t<Hogus>
{
  template <typename U>
  using inner_t_x = S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t_x<Bogus>;
};
```

then `S1_t<Bogus>::inner_t_x<Bogus>` and `S1_t<Hogus>::inner_t_x<Hogus>` would be the same type. Therefore, the template deduction in the partial specialization of `Functor2` could yield both `T=Bogus` or `T=Hogus`. Hence, it cannot be deduced unambiguously under any circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for a vivid example, suddenly it makes it very clear. Is there any way then to deduce the type T unambiguously ? My gut feel is that there is none, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to deduce the outer and the inner part of a nested type. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

`typename S1_t<T>::..`is not deducible in partial specialization.

You got a clearer error when using `inner_t` instead of `inner_t_x<T>`:

```
main.cpp:41:8: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:

 struct Functor2<typename S1_t<T>::inner_t>

        ^

main.cpp:41:8: note:         'T'

main.cpp:41:8: warning: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
```

Comment: References (relative to n4567): [temp.deduct.type]p5 and p6 *"When a type name is specified in a way that includes a non-deduced context, all of the types that comprise
that type name are also non-deduced."*

Comment: In other words, there is absolutely no way to deduce T. Is that correct? If so, I was mislead by lack of compiler warning thinking that type deduction was done on ::inner_t_x.